# Moment of Inertia equation for small volume

Tags: notation, integration, moment-of-inertia, calculus

Below is the equation of the moment of inertia for small volume elements, $\Delta m$

$$I = \lim_{\Delta m_i \to 0} \sum_{i} r^2_i \Delta m_i = \int r^2 dm$$

Can someone please explain it to me on how $$\lim_{\Delta m_i \to 0} \sum_{i} r^2_i \Delta m_i$$

can be equal to $$\int r^2 dm$$

Also, what is the different between $\Delta m$ and $dm$ ?

Answer (score 0):

The infinitesimal $dm$ is the limit of very small $\Delta m$. Since an integral is the limit of a sum of a large number of extremely small quantities, this notation makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite a shortened notation and one has to get acquainted  with it.
Here following all the intermediate steps.

Let's assume that the body of which you want to evaluate the inertia momentum around an axis is characterized by a mass density $\rho({\bf r})$. The mass of a small volume $\Delta V_i$  around the position ${\bf r}_i$ will be named 
$$
\Delta m_i = \rho({\bf r}_i)\Delta V_i.
$$
The volume has to be small enough so to make negligeable the variation of $\rho$ inside the volume.
Once the whole system has been divided into $N$ small subvolumes $\Delta V_i$ ($i=1,\dots,N$), the momentum of inertia around an axis is the sum of the squared distances of each point of the system from the axis times the corresponding mass. If we indicate by $r^2_i$ the square of the distance between the point ${\bf r}_i$ and the axis, we get, with the quantities introduced above:
$$
I = \sum_{i=1}^N r^2_i \Delta m_i~~~~~~~~~[1]
$$
For a continuous mass distribution $\rho({\bf r}_i)$, the previous formula is an approximation as better as smaller are the subvolumes $\Delta V_i$. The way to get rid of the discretization approximation is to evaluate the limit of formula $[1]$ using an increasingly number of subvolume to partition the total volume of the system.

The final result can be written as 
$$
I = \int_V r^2 \rho({\bf r})dV = \int_V r^2 dm,
$$
where, the last passage shows that the meaning of $dm$ should be intended as 
$dm = \rho({\bf r})dV$.